# How to ignore src, href in search query MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-regexp

I have a record in `product` table and have string field `content` like this

```
<div class="product">
    <a href="https://hostabc/item/3765/" target="_blank">
        <img alt="something" src="/hostabc/photo.jpg" width="100%"/>
    </a>
    <span>
        This is description of product and this doesn't contain 'hostabc' keyword !
    </span>
</div>
```

I use my keyword `hostabc` to search like `SELECT * FROM product WHERE content LIKE '%hostabc%'` and it returns this record.

So how to I ignore keyword `hostabc` in `src` or `href` on my search query (This record will be not found in search result.)

Can anyone help me !!!

Comment: Your question is generally hard to answer, because the "content" you are trying to search is nested HTML, and may not always appear at the same depth, or in the same way.  Regex is not the best tool for this job.

Comment: Do you have other solution for this problem @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Would the text to search _always_ appear inside `<span>` tags?

Comment: No. It's `content` of product and nested HTML so has many tags (p, span, div, ...)

Comment: Then pure MySQL is not the best tool to be using for this task.  You need an HTML parsing tool here.

Comment: I solved problem by use `REGEXP_REPLACE` (MySQL 8.0+)